# Producing a bibliography by chapter – have one reference in two chapters

Tags: citations, thesis, books

I am organising my bibliography by chapter to make for easier reading.

However, I have one source that I use in two chapters. Do I just include the reference in the bibliography for this in the first chapter it appears in?

Answer (score 5):

I can't give you an authoritative source at the moment, but I can't recall ever having had to look up a reference in a chapter different from the one in which it has been cited. It would also be very impractical: How would the reader know in which chapter the reference has been cited first?

Comment: In mathematics, this was a somewhat common occurrence back in the 50's and 60's (maybe in other times as well). If a work was used as a reference in several chapters, it was cited in each of those chapters. Some books even had suggestions for further reading attached to each chapter (some titles appeared in multiple chapters) in addition to a general bibliography.